# Maven Spring Boot Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory Reported exception:

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, slf4j

I am following the tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/

And when I try to run the App I get:

> Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory Reported exception:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:189)
>     at
>   hello.HelloWorldConfiguration.main(HelloWorldConfiguration.java:11)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 9 more
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:189)
>     at
>   hello.HelloWorldConfiguration.main(HelloWorldConfiguration.java:11)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 9 more

My pom file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>sample.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>api.test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>api.testMaven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <finalName>api.test</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

And I am at a loss for how to fix this issue. I tried cleaning and rebuilding, even re-importing. I looked at similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301569/failed-to-instantiate-slf4j-loggerfactory-on-spring-mvc-basic-tutorial)
but nothing seems to work.

The only way I got the program to run was by changing the parent pom to version `1.3.1.RELEASE` But I do not want to use this version and want to use `1.4.1.RELEASE`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ api.test ---
[INFO] sample.api:api.test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:comp
ile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.1.REL
EASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.1.R
ELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.1.RELEA
SE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.5:compile

[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.3:compile

[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.4.1.RELEAS
E:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:te
st
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.1.R
ELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Update

If I add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.5</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I get

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/C:/Users/Josh/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/C:/Users/Josh/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory Reported
>   exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:189)
>     at
>   hello.HelloWorldConfiguration.main(HelloWorldConfiguration.java:11)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 9 more
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:189)
>     at
>   hello.HelloWorldConfiguration.main(HelloWorldConfiguration.java:11)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 9 more

Comment: I think issue is with your local repository, can you clean it and build from scratch with original dependencies.

Comment: I have ran maven clean, maven update project, and maven install. I still get the same errors

Comment: Remove the added dependencies (leave on the `spring-boot-starter-*` ones). Run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to remove all dependencies and force a re-download. Then do a `mvn clean verify` (or whatever you use to create your artifact). Looks like your logback. jar is corrupt somehow and this forces a redownload.

Answer (score 38):

Below actions worked for me

1. Run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to remove all dependencies and force a re-download.
2. Then do a `mvn clean verify`

Comment: Worked for me to.   (Navigate to the project folder and RUN -> mvn dependency:purge-local-repository).   Thanks Adi!

Comment: Awesome. Initially this did not work for me. When I deleted .m2/repository and then used the above command. It worked.

Answer (score 9):

I add this dependency and problem resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

you just use version of logback-classic if [this](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1269) error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find log4j and add in your classpath.

Comment: What dependency would that go along with? I have tried it alone with `spring-boot-starter-web` and alone with `spring-boot-starter-actuator` but neither seem to work

Comment: Actually lets try going the other way. try including them

Comment: Updated answer to show results from adding dependencies

Answer (score 0):

See that message: (you manage dependency duplicate, for dependency transitive, that cause dependency duplicate with differents versions)

> Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in

make a test if use IDE Eclipse

short cut key: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

that way you see what file has contains this class:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:
/C:/Users/Josh/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!
/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[jar:file:/C:/Users/Josh/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!
/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

repeat class in

```
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar
logback-classic-1.1.7.jar
```

find your same  dependency and exclusion what don't you need in your project

that way:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
<scope>test</scope>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

that one example, change for your context

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not exists with version 1.3.5. I changed my version to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

It works !!

Comment: What if we need to use the most recent spring boot version? It doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a version problem, 
I change my version of springboot from 2.0.0.RELEASE to 1.5.4.RELEASE,
the exception disappeared.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can skip logging dependency and it will work for us.

```
`<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>`
```