# Creating two tables from single entity in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

means i need to trace the original table similar to logging the table with values and the operations that has been taken

I have entity like

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long _id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String imageUrl;
```

So whatever the operations like adding,modifying has to be stored in the log table with the values.

Guide me to achieve this in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring JPA Auditing for solving this.

Main entity class:

```
@Entity @EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long _id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String imageUrl;
    // Getter Setter
}
```

Audit Listener class:

```
@Component
public class MyEntityListener {

    @Autowired
    private LogEntryRepositoy logEntryRepositoy;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    @PreRemove
    private void beforeAnyOperation(MyEntity myEntity) { 

        LogEntry entry = new LogEntry();
        //Your custom logic
        logEntryRepositoy.save(entry);
    }
}
```

Your Log entity:

```
@Entity
public class LogEntry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long _id;
    private String operation;
    //Add other properties

}
```

Your Log Repository

```
@Repository
public interface LogEntryRepositoy extends JpaRepository<LogEntry, Long> {

}
```

Spring boot application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

for further reading follow this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html)

[GitHub Demo project](https://github.com/yogi21jan/jpa-audit-demo)

If You are using any other database other than h2,configure that in application properties.

For e.g If you are using MySQL:

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/_your_data_name
spring.datasource.username=your_user_name
spring.datasource.password=your_password
```

And dependency of MySQL in pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: sir thanks for the response and sorry for the late reply. I applied the same to my module but it ends up with error only. What i did was i am taking values from html by script, convert as JSON object and pass through the controller and then to database. But the values are not storing in the DB and failed message only returning as response. Please help me to fix this and what is meant by the custom logic in your reply. As i am newbie please ignore if i ask any silly questions.

Comment: can you please post a link or a simple and complete example with the output that what we need.

Comment: I have added GitHub link for working code...check my response has GitHub demo project link..

Comment: Sir, if i run this project i am getting the below error and i am using mySQL database for this project but u given H2 database so how will i get it in the MySQL database.

`Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory

Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/LifeCycle`

Comment: For logging exception..follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138247/maven-spring-boot-failed-to-instantiate-slf4j-loggerfactory-reported-exception

Comment: sir ... i have added the dependency as well as in the application properties file for the database configuration but i spent yesterday fully on resolving the LoggerFactory error but still i cant able to resolve it. If i excluded the unnecassary maven dependency means a new error will come like that i am struggling a full day in resolving the LoggerFactory error and i am running this application in STS.

`Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/LifeCycle`

Comment: Add  below dependency in your pom file: <dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Sir, I have added the logback classic file in both dependency and in external jar file also but i received the same error message only. For now i just set the values from the original entity to the log file in the manual way and all the values are storing in the log file. If i get any demo or using fiddle method it will be more helpful to me sir... and great thanks for your suggestions